# how to print the currentregion of a list in vba

Tags: vba, excel, printing

I have been asked to print out a filtered list, however the list is dynamic in that the filtered dataset can produce different results.  I have this code, but it does not print.

```
ActiveSheet.PageSetup.PrintArea = Range("E3").CurrentRegion.Address
```

Would someone be able to assist me with this.

Comment: This just sets the printarea, it's not a command to print something. You probably want to use [.PrintOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838253.aspx) for that.

Comment: I did add .printout and it in fact did print, however I get an error 1004, unable to set the PrintArea property of the PageSetup class.

Comment: can you change any other properties of the PageSetup class?